# How can render a Block on a Contact form Page

Tags: emails, theming

I want to render a Block on a special content type page and on the contact form page. All works fine, but i didn`t found any way to print the Block also on the contact form page.

i use in the page.tpl.php:

```
if(isset($node) && $node->type === 'page') {
   ....
}
```

Hope someone can help! Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the logic exactly as you have laid it out, you could test for

```
if (arg(0) == 'contact')
```

to output the block on the contact page. However, is there a reason you're not using the block admin page to place this block instead? Other options here that might be easier to maintain would be:

- place the block in the region you want using the Context module
- copy the page.tpl.php file from your theme to page--contact.tpl.php and add your block content there

Comment: Hey, great thanks to you! I need the block twice, for the footer and for some content pages in one sidebar ... i hoped this was the easier way, but i didn`t found a solution for the contact page ... think yours should work!